# How can i convert NSBezierPath to CGPath

Tags: cocoa, cgpath, nsbezierpath

How can i convert between `NSBezierPath` to `CGPath`.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of that question. That's asking about how to stuff a CGPath into an archive or otherwise serialize it; this is about converting from one kind of path object to another, without necessarily serializing from one and deserializing to the other.

Comment: I like this one, a library that adds UIKit functionality to the MacOS. Once included, you can set and read the `CGPath` for a `NSBezierPath`
https://github.com/iccir/XUIKit

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Right from Apple documentation: [Creating a CGPathRef From an NSBezierPath Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-SW2)

Here is the relevant code.

```
@implementation NSBezierPath (BezierPathQuartzUtilities)
// This method works only in OS X v10.2 and later.
- (CGPathRef)quartzPath
{
    int i, numElements;

    // Need to begin a path here.
    CGPathRef           immutablePath = NULL;

    // Then draw the path elements.
    numElements = [self elementCount];
    if (numElements > 0)
    {
        CGMutablePathRef    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        NSPoint             points[3];
        BOOL                didClosePath = YES;

        for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
        {
            switch ([self elementAtIndex:i associatedPoints:points])
            {
                case NSMoveToBezierPathElement:
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, points[0].x, points[0].y);
                    break;

                case NSLineToBezierPathElement:
                    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, points[0].x, points[0].y);
                    didClosePath = NO;
                    break;

                case NSCurveToBezierPathElement:
                    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, points[0].x, points[0].y,
                                        points[1].x, points[1].y,
                                        points[2].x, points[2].y);
                    didClosePath = NO;
                    break;

                case NSClosePathBezierPathElement:
                    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
                    didClosePath = YES;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Be sure the path is closed or Quartz may not do valid hit detection.
        if (!didClosePath)
            CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

        immutablePath = CGPathCreateCopy(path);
        CGPathRelease(path);
    }

    return immutablePath;
}
@end
```

#### Bug Reporter

[rdar://15758302](http://rdar://15758302): NSBezierPath to CGPath.

Comment: I think it's quite amazing that Apple puts that code in the docs instead of just adding a `CGPath` accessor to `NSBezierPath`.

Answer (score 34):

The syntax in Xcode 8 GM has been further simplified, code modified from rob-mayoff's answer above. Using this and a helper for `addLine(to point: CGPoint)` I am sharing drawing code cross platform.

```
extension NSBezierPath {

    public var cgPath: CGPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        var points = [CGPoint](repeating: .zero, count: 3)

        for i in 0 ..< elementCount {
            let type = element(at: i, associatedPoints: &points)
            switch type {
            case .moveTo:
                path.move(to: points[0])
            case .lineTo:
                path.addLine(to: points[0])
            case .curveTo:
                path.addCurve(to: points[2], control1: points[0], control2: points[1])
            case .closePath:
                path.closeSubpath()
            @unknown default:
                continue
            }
        }

        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This works in Swift 3.1 and later:

```
import AppKit

public extension NSBezierPath {

    public var cgPath: CGPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        var points = [CGPoint](repeating: .zero, count: 3)
        for i in 0 ..< self.elementCount {
            let type = self.element(at: i, associatedPoints: &points)
            switch type {
            case .moveToBezierPathElement: path.move(to: points[0])
            case .lineToBezierPathElement: path.addLine(to: points[0])
            case .curveToBezierPathElement: path.addCurve(to: points[2], control1: points[0], control2: points[1])
            case .closePathBezierPathElement: path.closeSubpath()
            }
        }
        return path
    }

}
```

Comment: There are no such things as moveTo or addLineTo in Swift 3, are they?

Comment: This would be nicer as a convenience initializer on `CGPath`, so one could use the more-standard `CGPath(from: bezierPath)` syntax

Comment: `NSColor` has a `cgColor` property, `NSGraphicsContext` has a `cgContext` property, and `NSColorSpace` has a `cgColorSpace` property. `NSImage` has ` cgImage(forProposedRect:context:hints:)` method.

Comment: Also, Swift does not support convenience initializers on `CGPath`. If you try to declare one, you get the error “Convenience initializers are not supported in extensions of CF types”.

Answer (score 17):

For macOS better use - [CGMutablePath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgmutablepath)

But, if you want `cgPath` for `NSBezierPath`:

**Swift 5.0**

```
extension NSBezierPath {

  var cgPath: CGPath {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    var points = [CGPoint](repeating: .zero, count: 3)
    for i in 0 ..< self.elementCount {
      let type = self.element(at: i, associatedPoints: &points)

      switch type {
      case .moveTo:
        path.move(to: points[0])

      case .lineTo:
        path.addLine(to: points[0])

      case .curveTo:
        path.addCurve(to: points[2], control1: points[0], control2: points[1])

      case .closePath:
        path.closeSubpath()

      @unknown default:
        break
      }
    }
    return path
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Swift version if anyone else finds a need for it:

```
extension IXBezierPath {
// Adapted from : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-SW2
// See also: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/370959-nsbezierpath-to-cgpathref-in-swift/
func CGPath(forceClose forceClose:Bool) -> CGPathRef? {
    var cgPath:CGPathRef? = nil

    let numElements = self.elementCount
    if numElements > 0 {
        let newPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
        let points = NSPointArray.alloc(3)
        var bDidClosePath:Bool = true

        for i in 0 ..< numElements {

            switch elementAtIndex(i, associatedPoints:points) {

            case NSBezierPathElement.MoveToBezierPathElement:
                CGPathMoveToPoint(newPath, nil, points[0].x, points[0].y )

            case NSBezierPathElement.LineToBezierPathElement:
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(newPath, nil, points[0].x, points[0].y )
                bDidClosePath = false

            case NSBezierPathElement.CurveToBezierPathElement:
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(newPath, nil, points[0].x, points[0].y, points[1].x, points[1].y, points[2].x, points[2].y )
                bDidClosePath = false

            case NSBezierPathElement.ClosePathBezierPathElement:
                CGPathCloseSubpath(newPath)
                bDidClosePath = true
            }

            if forceClose && !bDidClosePath {
                CGPathCloseSubpath(newPath)
            }
        }
        cgPath = CGPathCreateCopy(newPath)
    }
    return cgPath
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't figure out why the accepted answer adds some sophisticated close-path logic (maybe it is needed under some circumstances), but for those who just need a *pristine* conversion of the path, here is cleaned version of that code, implemented as a regular method:

```
- (CGMutablePathRef)CGPathFromPath:(NSBezierPath *)path
{
    CGMutablePathRef cgPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    NSInteger n = [path elementCount];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        NSPoint ps[3];
        switch ([path elementAtIndex:i associatedPoints:ps]) {
            case NSMoveToBezierPathElement: {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(cgPath, NULL, ps[0].x, ps[0].y);
                break;
            }
            case NSLineToBezierPathElement: {
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(cgPath, NULL, ps[0].x, ps[0].y);
                break;
            }
            case NSCurveToBezierPathElement: {
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(cgPath, NULL, ps[0].x, ps[0].y, ps[1].x, ps[1].y, ps[2].x, ps[2].y);
                break;
            }
            case NSClosePathBezierPathElement: {
                CGPathCloseSubpath(cgPath);
                break;
            }
            default: NSAssert(0, @"Invalid NSBezierPathElement");
        }
    }
    return cgPath;
}
```

---

Btw, I needed this to implement "NSBezierPath stroke contains point" method.

I've looked for this conversion to call `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath()`, that converts `NSBezierPath` stroke outline to regular path, so you can test hits on strokes too, and here is the solution:

```
// stroke (0,0) to (10,0) width 5 --> rect (0, -2.5) (10 x 5)
NSBezierPath *path = [[NSBezierPath alloc] init];
[path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0)];
[path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(10.0, 0.0)];
[path setLineWidth:5.0];

CGMutablePathRef cgPath = [self CGPathFromPath:path];
CGPathRef strokePath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(cgPath, NULL, [path lineWidth], [path lineCapStyle],
                                                      [path lineJoinStyle], [path miterLimit]);
CGPathRelease(cgPath);

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(NSRectFromCGRect(CGPathGetBoundingBox(strokePath))));
// {{0, -2.5}, {10, 5}}

CGPoint point = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
BOOL hit = CGPathContainsPoint(strokePath, NULL, point, (bool)[path windingRule]);

NSLog(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromPoint(NSPointFromCGPoint(point)), (hit ? @"yes" : @"no"));
// {1, 1}: yes

CGPathRelease(strokePath);
```

This is similar to `QPainterPathStroker` from Qt, but for `NSBezierPath`.

Answer (score 2):

c# Xamarin

```
        private CGPath convertNSBezierPathToCGPath(NSBezierPath sourcePath)
    {
        CGPath destinationPath = new CGPath();

        int i, numElements;

        // Then draw the path elements.
        numElements = (int)Convert.ToInt64(sourcePath.ElementCount);

        if (numElements > 0)
        {

            CGPath path = new CGPath();
            CGPoint[] points;
            bool didClosePath = true;

            for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            {
                switch (sourcePath.ElementAt(i, out points))
                {
                    case NSBezierPathElement.MoveTo:
                        path.MoveToPoint(points[0]);
                        break;


                    case NSBezierPathElement.LineTo:
                        path.MoveToPoint(points[0]);
                        didClosePath = false;
                        break;

                    case NSBezierPathElement.CurveTo:
                        path.AddCurveToPoint(cp1: points[0], cp2: points[1], points[2]);
                        didClosePath = false;
                        break;

                    case NSBezierPathElement.ClosePath:
                        path.CloseSubpath();
                        didClosePath = true;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (!didClosePath)
                path.CloseSubpath();

            destinationPath = new CGPath(path);

        }

        return destinationPath;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting macOS 14 then `cgPath` is already part of the `NSBezierPath`  API.

WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10054/?time=676

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbezierpath/4191603-cgpath